# Why is my hex code generator returning variable names instead of their values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to create a random hex code generator. So far I am just trying to get the 6 random values to be presented in the HTML.

```
    // Letters A-F can be used and numbers 0-9
var button = document.querySelector(".hex-btn");
var color = document.querySelector(".chosen-color");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var letterString = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
  var chosenLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var letter = letterString[chosenLetter];

  hex1 = hexOptions();
  hex2 = hexOptions();
  hex3 = hexOptions();
  hex4 = hexOptions();
  hex5 = hexOptions();
  hex6 = hexOptions();

  color.innerHTML = "#" + hex1 + hex2 + hex3 + hex4 + hex5 + hex6;
});

//So each hex value can be number or letter 
function hexOptions() {
  var option = ["number", "letter"];
  var randomOption = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  return option[randomOption];
}
```

Why is it returning the names of the variables rather than their values? Ex. #numbernumberletternumberletternumber

Comment: 1) Please add your HTML to make a [mre]. 2) The `option` array contains 2 string, what did you expect as value? 3) `number ` and `letter` varibales are never used.

Comment: Your array contains strings, not the values of variables. Also, why so complicated? You could just create a random number between 0x000000 and 0xFFFFFF and return it in hex. `color.innerText = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')` (instead of this whole ordeal). Right now your random number isn't even so random because it will only ever have one different number and one different letter in the result at a time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `hexOptions` function returns the string of either 'number' or 'letter'
You then assign the variables `hex1` through to `hex6` as the result of this function, concatenate them and return.

What you probably want is to use the result of `hexOptions` to choose either a letter or a number. Something like:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var letterString = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
  var chosenLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var letter = letterString[chosenLetter];

  hex1 = hexOptions();
  const hex1Value = hex1 === 'number' ? Math.random() * 10 : letter;
  // repeat for each of your hex values

  color.innerHTML = "#" + hex1Value + hex2Value + hex3Value + hex4Value + hex5Value + hex6Value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to javascript and I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your question above is why you get the result that you're getting. I will be answering exactly that.

```
var option = ["number", "letter"];
```

This is an array that contains 2 strings. Surely you're trying to do something else with that.

Calling option[0] on the above would return the word "number". That's the reason you're getting that result.